# Creating a new object and storing that object in a new class' vector, attributes disappear

Tags: c++, class, vector

Bit of a long title so I am sorry with that. But I do have a bit of a problem with my code at the moment. It should be pretty general and there is quite a bit going on in the code so I won't post it all but I do have this one problem. Here it is:

```
Sentence newSentence(currentSentence, this, sentenceCount);
this->sentencesNonP.push_back(newSentence);
```

Now, `newSentence` has an attribute called `words` which is of type `std::vector<Word *>`, `Word` is also another class within the project.

When I am debugging and checking the attributes of `newSentence` it shows that `words` is populated with a length of 4, however when I check `sentencesNonP`, which is a `std::vector<Sentence>`, the `words` vector length is `0`. I am checking the first point at `sentencesNonP` because it is the first the first value being pushed in so it's not that I'm looking at the wrong location of the `sentencesNonP` vector.

Any reason why my data is being lost in the conversion process?

EDIT: I have implemented both a `=` operator overload and a copy operator. However, `words` is still empty in `sentencesNonP`.

EDIT2:
Sentence.h (excluding include's)

```
class Word;
class Document;

class Sentence {
public:
    //Take out Document * document
    Sentence();
    Sentence(std::string value, Document * document = NULL, int senNum = 0);
    Sentence(const Sentence& newSent);
    //Sentence(std::string value);
    ~Sentence(void);

    Sentence & operator=(const Sentence newSent);

    Document * getDocument(void);
    void setDocument(Document * document);
    //__declspec(property(get = getDocument, put = setDocument)) Document * document;

    std::string getSentence(void);
    void setSentence(std::string word);
    //__declspec(property(get = getSentence, put = setSentence)) std::string str;

    void setSentenceNumber(unsigned int i);

    Word * operator[] (unsigned int i);
    unsigned int wordCount(void);
    unsigned int charCount(void);
    unsigned int sentenceNumber(void);

    std::vector<Word *> getWordsVector(void);

private:
    std::string sentence;
    std::vector<Word *> words;
    std::vector<Word> wordNonP;
    Document * myd;
    unsigned int senNum;
};
```

Ignore the commented out `declspec`

EDIT3: Here is my copy constructor:

```
Sentence::Sentence(const Sentence& newSent) {
    this->sentence = newSent.sentence;
    this->myd = newSent.myd;
    this->senNum = newSent.senNum;
    for (int i = 0; i < newSent.wordNonP.size(); i++) {
        this->wordNonP.push_back(newSent.wordNonP[i]);
        this->words.push_back(newSent.words[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the copy constructor of `Sentence` do? It must have lost the attributes on the way.

Comment: That's what I did think as well, but there is no overloaded `=` operator. Should I implement one and see if it works then? Didn't really think it would need one since it's only being pushed onto a vector.

Comment: Wait, is it `=` overload or another operator?

Comment: It must be copy constructor: `Sentence(const Sentence&)`. Overloaded `=` is assignment operator, that's a different beast.

Comment: Okay, I'll go ahead and implement that one now. If you check back soon, I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: ... and perhaps you need both of them.

Comment: Okay, I'll add them both now, should do the exact same thing anyway. I am having a problem implementing the copy operator though. I have this `Sentence(const Sentence& newSent)` and within that I have `newSent.sentence = this->sentence`. `sentence` is only a `std::string` but it is saying `No viable overloaded '='`?

Comment: You should do it other way round :) `newSent` is source, and `this` is destination!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is The Rule of Three?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: Ahhh true, blimey. Thanks, Vlad. Okay, impleementing them now. What's that Fred? EDIT: Ahh, yes it is Fred, well, it sounds like it anyway.

Comment: After both the copy and the `=` operator have been implemented, `sentencesNonP` is still saying that `words` is empty even though `newSentence` still has a populated `words` vector...

Comment: Can we see the definition of `Sentence`?

Comment: As in the constructor @FredOverflow

Comment: show the copy constructor definition.

Comment: Okay, adding now @deadmg

Comment: Why do you have a `vector<Word*>` as opposed to a `vector<Word>`?

Comment: There is both there, @fred only because the Words are allocated memory during the Sentence constructor and if I store a pointer to them in the class, the pointers will point to nothing. Since this is for an assignment, the lecturer wants an attribute of type `vector<Word *>` so I store the `Word` in the class and in the Sentence Constructor, populate the `Word *` vector with a reference to the `Word` vector's elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < newSent.wordNonP.size(); i++) {
    this->wordNonP.push_back(newSent.wordNonP[i]);
    this->words.push_back(newSent.words[i]);
}
```

If `wordNonP` is empty you won't copy any `words` at all. Write either:

```
for (int i = 0; i < newSent.wordNonP.size(); i++)
    this->wordNonP.push_back(newSent.wordNonP[i]);
for (int i = 0; i < newSent.words.size(); i++)
    this->words.push_back(newSent.words[i]);
```

Or even simpler:

```
this->wordNonP = newSent.wordNonP;
this->words = newSent.words;
```

Comment: `words` is actually a vector of pointers to each element in `wordNonP`, so that's why I wrote my copy constructor the way I did. Changing to the way you have, it still won't work though. I do thank-you for your suggestion and I have changed the code a little bit. EDIT: As I mentioned though, it still won't copy across all the words stored in the vector?